# Calculating the efficiency of an audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio

I'm looking at the [PAM8406](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8406.pdf) Class-D/Class-AB amplifier and I'm not seeing the efficiency for a 2Ω load in Class-AB mode. The use case for the amplifier is driving mid-range/mid-bass speakers for use with a telephony system (essentially, no music will be output from the amp, and it will only be on for short a duration of time).

From what I've read, Class-D amplifiers are better suited to drive sub-woofers and other bass intensive applications, where as Class-AB is less efficient but more suitable for general audio applications.

- How can I calculate the efficiency of this amplifier?
- Is there a more suitable alternative to this amplifier for my use case? I need at least 2W into a 2-Ω load.

Comment: "What I've read, class-D … are better suited to drive … bass, whereas class-AB is less efficient but more suitable for general audio" I don't share that sentiment. Class D works fine for high audible frequencies, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is unique with no filter and optional dual class D or AB with differential drive , no pops and 4W from 5Vdc into 2 Ohms.

Since both Pch,Nch  class D drivers are each less than 10% of 2 Ohms the losses are 20% max with 2Ohm speaker and 10% max with 8 Ohms.

Datasheet:
η Efficiency Class D Mode f = 1kHz

RL =8Ω,THD=10%
90%
RL =4Ω,THD=10%
85%
RL =2Ω,THD=10%
80%

Class AB is always much less than 65% depending on peak to RMS crest factor